# What is considered best practice when importing data in a 'pipeline'?

Tags: r

Let's say I have some sort of process that takes data from a CSV that is located on my local machine. This process will eventually need to be scheduled via some cron job. I need to import that data obviously and if I'm writing an automated script there are two main solutions for this.

Create a user defined function that includes the import statement in the body.

```
    import_data_and_clean <- function(full_path){
         data = read_csv(path)
         ....
    }
```

Create a dataset_builder.R file that not only imports the data, but also cleans and prepared the data for analysis.

```
data = read_csv(path)
....
```

My question pertains to which of these solutions was the reccomended way to do this in R?